# WP7 Text-To-Speech Playing Whole Collection At Once

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, text-to-speech

I working on a Windows Phone 7 app with Text-To-Speech capabilities.  I'm using [Text-To-Speech with Microsoft Translator Service](http://translatorservice.codeplex.com/) and the following C# code...

```
// Text-To-Speech with Microsoft Translator Service (http://translatorservice.codeplex.com/)
private void TextToSpeech_Play(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SpeechSynthesizer speech = new SpeechSynthesizer(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);
    //string content = "This is a beautiful day!";
    string language = "en";
    //speech.SpeakAsync(content, language);

    foreach (UIElement element in todayschapter.Children)
    {
        if (element is TextBlock)
        {
            string content = (element as TextBlock).Text;
            speech.SpeakAsync(content, language);
        }
    }
}
```

In this instance, todayschapter is a StackPanel and its Children are TextBlocks.  I'm wanting to simply play audio of each TextBlock, in succession.  The problem is that it is play the audio of EVERY TextBlock at the same time.

I have a sneaking suspicion that the problem is `SpeakAsync()`, but I'm not sure.  The [documentation](http://translatorservice.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=.NET%204.0%20documentation) shows `Speak()`, but that isn't available (maybe a different version) in the Visual Studio methods helper dropdown (little thing that shows as you type - not sure what it's called).

Is there a way to make it wait for each play to finish before playing the next?  Is `foreach` not the right choice, for this?

As always, if my code just looks stupid, please recommend better ways.  I'm very much a beginner programmer.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `Speak` instead of the async call, since you want to have it one after another anyway.

Comment: Haven't tried that myself either, await needs a Task to be returned, and the event might not be available in WP7, also, don't accept as answer if it doesn't help you.

Comment: I noted that `Speak()` isn't allowed.  The only thing that I can think of is that the .NET version supports more things than the WP version.

Comment: I'd rather not -1 your edit (not helpful, anymore).  I think your first post was more helpful, unless there is actually something wrong with it.

Comment: There is no point in calling async if you want it sequentially anyway. You'll make it more complicated without any benefit.

Comment: The problem is that `Speak` doesn't seem to be available.  Yes, it would be logical to no use an asynchronous option, but there isn't one.  The only other choice would be to use a totally different Text-To-Speech utility (which may be the right choice).

Answer (score 0):

The `SpeakAsync` call is indeed the problem.  Unfortunately, since `SpeakAsync` doesn't return a `Task`, you can't just convert this to `await SpeakAsync()` (which would be the most straightforward conversion).

And, looking at the source code, it doesn't fire an event to tell when it's done.  So let's add one (in SpeechSynthesizer.cs):

```
    public event EventHandler<SpeechEventArgs> SpeakCompleted;

    public void SpeakAsync(string text, string language)
    {
        this.GetSpeakStreamAsyncHelper(text, language, result =>
        {
            if (result.Error == null)
            {
                SoundEffect effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(result.Stream);
                FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
                effect.Play();
                this.OnSpeakCompleted(new SpeechEventArgs(result.Error));            // added to call completion handler
            }
            else
            {
                this.OnSpeakFailed(new SpeechEventArgs(result.Error));
            }
        });
    }
// new function
    private void OnSpeakCompleted(SpeechEventArgs e)
    {
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            if (SpeakCompleted != null)
                SpeakCompleted(this, e);
        });
    }
```

Now, you'll need to handle the [`SpeakCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.speakcompleted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event and start speaking the next string.

Something like this (I haven't even compiled this, so be warned):

```
private Queue<string> utterances;
private SpeechSynthesizer speech;
private void TextToSpeech_Play(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    speech = new SpeechSynthesizer(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);
    speech.SpeechCompleted += new EventHandler<SpeechEventArgs>(TextToSpeech_Completed); 

    foreach (UIElement element in todayschapter.Children)
    {
        if (element is TextBlock)
        {
            string content = (element as TextBlock).Text;
            utterances.Enqueue(content);
        }
    }
    TextToSpeech_Completed(null, null);   // start speaking the first one
}

private void TextToSpeech_Completed(object sender, SpeechEventArgs e)
{
     if (utterances.Any())
     {
         string contents = utterances.Dequeue();
         speech.SpeakAsync(contents);
     }
}
```

Comment: I didn't know anything about `Queue`.  Thanks for another option.  I'll give it a whirl, tonight.

Comment: @doubleJ Another option is to build one big string and speak that asynchronously.  Sooner or later, though, you're going to have to build some sort of queue to handle requests.

Comment: Well, crap...The only Completed options are `DetectLanguagesCompleted`, `GetLanguagesCompleted`, `GetSpeakStreamCompleted`, and `TranslateCompleted`.

Comment: @doubleJ `GetSpeakStreamCompleted` seems like it ought to do the job.

Comment: Yes, but that involves an extra level of complication that goes beyond my skill level.  Hehehe...  After receiving the stream, then I'll have to play the stream.  Then I'll have to do some other code to make sure that the previous audio has stopped, before starting the next one.  I'm considering just trying a different text-to-speech option, at this point.  Of course, playing back the audio may not even be that important.  Hehehe...  Honestly, I wish they just had the documented options.

Comment: So, I reviewed the codeplex project, and it turns out to be pretty easy to add a real SpeakCompleted event.  I've updated the answer to match.

Comment: I'm glad that looks easy, to you.  Hehehe...  How is it that you're making a call to `speech.SpeechCompleted`?  It's been established that the only Completed options are what I listed above (of which `SpeechCompleted` isn't one.

Comment: @double That's because I *created* one.  You have the source (it's on CodePlex), and it doesn't do what you want; change it until it does.

Comment: Ah, well that makes sense.  Here's a worthwhile question...If you're going to the trouble to make a whole new thing, wouldn't it be easier to create the normal synchronous commands?  It seems like extra work to do all the asynchronous stuff.  Of course, async is probably better.

Comment: @double Going fully synchronous requires more code than I care to write in an answer.  Feel free to expand on it.  Bear in mind that you likely want to overlap the translation requests with the audio playing, otherwise you're going to end up with 5-6 second pauses between sections.  Fixing *that* is doable (you need two queues, basically), but not something I'm going to dash off for an answer.

Comment: Wow, I'm surprised that synchronous would require more code.  It seemed to me that asynchronous usually did.  Regardless, thanks for all the help.  You've done a lot more than I figured would be necessary.